# TypeScript - Use modules or classes with unit testing in mind?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Which strategy of content architecture is best with unit testing in mind in TypeScript? Creating modules or classes?

module: `moduleX.method1();` // Exported method

class: `var x = moduleX.method1();` // Public method

Comment: It shouldn't be decided based on testing. Modules and classes are just different. You can't extend a module for example (not as easily as with classes that is). Some things are better done with modules and some with classes. Also, there's no contradiction, you can have classes in modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> best with unit testing in mind in TypeScript

If you have a function that doesn't depend on local state in a class .... then it should just be a function. No need to `new SomeClass().foo()` when you can `foo()`

Here you can use namespaces to offer a nice consolidation of different function into a single object : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/namespaces.html and you get something like `Utils.foo()`

Be warned that I would prefer you just make a *javascript module* instead of a namespace : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Most importantly *have fun*  As long as you are consistent and considerate of the next developer (leave comments / types) you can focus on the business logic.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. In my case, I'm working on a drawing tool app. I have everything wrapped in a namespace with variables inside, one function is exported and when called sets the canvas up and adds event listeners for the controls. The other functions are then called and use and update the shared variables. I'm wondering if I should switch this to a class instead and change to use properties instead of variables.

Comment: `I'm wondering if I should switch this to a class instead and change to use properties instead of variables`. I would : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/classesAreUseful.html